# VIM: Set a key mapping to replace ampersand (&) at a set column

Tags: vim

I would like to set up a key mapping so that when I type this key (specifically the F7 key in my example), it replaces whatever character is in column 6 with an ampersand (&).

I am trying

```
:nnoremap <F7> 6| R &<ESC>
```

Yet that doesn't seem to be doing the trick and I cannot seem to grasp why.

Why is what I'm trying wrong?

Comment: Given that you have tagged this relating to Fortran, do you care whether that character is a blank or a zero?

Comment: I don't really care what the identity of this character is. If I understand the fixed-form Fortran standards well enough, simply placing any non-blank character in column 6 allows the next line to continue from where the previous one ended. I just tagged this with Fortran because of this motivation in case other Fortran developers had tackled this problem.

Comment: The reason I asked is precisely because `0` in column 6 is different from `&` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, it may also be useful to move the cursor back to its original position (i.e. the location before the replacement). To do this use:

```
nnoremap <F7> :let a=getpos(".")<cr>6\|r&:call cursor(a[1],a[2])<cr>
```

this map is broken up like this:

- `:let a=getpos(".")<cr>` saves the cursor position on variable `a`
- `6\|r&` is explained in an earlier answer
- `:call cursor(a[1],a[2])<cr>` returns the cursor to its original position

Answer (score 2):

> Yet that doesn't seem to be doing the trick and I cannot seem to grasp why.

So… what does it do instead of what you expect?

Anyway, there are a number of problems with your mapping:

1. You can't use a literal pipe character in a mapping. You must escape it (`\|`) or use `<bar>` instead, which gives us the following:

   ```
   nnoremap <F7> 6\| R &<Esc>
   nnoremap <F7> 6<Bar> R &<Esc>
   ```

   See `:help map-bar`.
2. In your macro, the `<Space>` character () is interpreted as the `<Space>` command and thus moves the cursor one character to the right. If you don't mean `<Space>` (the command) don't use `<Space>` (the character):

   ```
   nnoremap <F7> 6\|R&<Esc>
   ```
3. `R` puts you in replace mode. This is useless because you are only replacing one character and it forces you to `<Esc>` to normal mode. Use `r` instead:

   ```
   nnoremap <F7> 6\|r&
   ```

   See `:help R` and `:help r`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
:map <F7> 05lr&
```

No escape.  Just type that and hit enter.  The  is really typing out those characters -- less than sign, capital F, the number 7, etc..